# Find matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1}AP=B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

> Given $$A = \begin{bmatrix}
> 1 & 0 & 0 \\
> 0 & 2 & -3 \\
> 1 & 3 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$$ $$B= \begin{bmatrix}
> 1 & 0 & 0 \\
> 0 & 2 & -3 \\
> 0 & 3 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$$ find $P$ such that $P^{-1} A P = B$.

Firstly I said that $AP=PB$

Solved the 9 equations in 9 unknowns. and got that:

$$P= \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
-10x & 0 & 0 \\
3x & y & z \\
x & -z & y \end{array} \right)$$

Then I used computer to find $P^{-1}$ in terms of those unknowns and plugged it back in to

$P^{-1}AP=B$

Compared the coefficients and i end up with 
$B= \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
-z/10x & 2 & -3 \\
1-y/10x & 3 & 2 \end{array} \right) $

Set $x=1$, $y=10$, $z=0$ and indeed $P^{-1}AP=B$

The doubts I am having is the fact that P is not unique. I could set x,y,z to different numbers.

Can anyone explain this? Thank you.

Comment: Left multiply both sides by $P$? Is there a better method?

Comment: That is very true. Thank you. I believe it won't change anything no matter which way i do it?

Comment: Suppose that $P$ solves your problem, then $\alpha P$ will also solve it for any $\alpha \neq 0$ so the solution is never unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [SymPy](http://live.sympy.org):

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> X = MatrixSymbol('X',3,3)
>>> A = Matrix([[ 1, 0, 0],
                [ 0, 2,-3],
                [ 1, 3, 2]])
>>> B = Matrix([[ 1, 0, 0],
                [ 0, 2,-3],
                [ 0, 3, 2]])
>>> simplify(Matrix(A*X - X*B))
Matrix([
[                            0,            -X[0, 1] - 3*X[0, 2],             3*X[0, 1] - X[0, 2]],
[          X[1, 0] - 3*X[2, 0],          -3*(X[1, 2] + X[2, 1]),           3*(X[1, 1] - X[2, 2])],
[X[0, 0] + 3*X[1, 0] + X[2, 0], X[0, 1] + 3*X[1, 1] - 3*X[2, 2], X[0, 2] + 3*X[1, 2] + 3*X[2, 1]]])
```

If $\rm A X - X B = O_3$, we have an *underdetermined* homogeneous system of $3^2 - 1$ linear equations in $3^2$ unknowns. Thus, we have *at least* $1$ degree of freedom. We vectorize the matrix equation

$$\left( \mathrm I_3 \otimes \mathrm A - \mathrm B^{\top} \otimes \mathrm I_3 \right) \mbox{vec} (\mathrm X) = 0_9$$

and let $\mathrm M := \mathrm I_3 \otimes \mathrm A - \mathrm B^{\top} \otimes \mathrm I_3$. Using [SymPy](http://live.sympy.org):

```
>>> I3 = Identity(3)
>>> O3 = ZeroMatrix(3,3)
>>> M = BlockMatrix([[A - I3,       O3,       O3],
                     [    O3, A - 2*I3,    -3*I3], 
                     [    O3,     3*I3, A - 2*I3]])
>>> Matrix(M)
Matrix([
[0, 0,  0,  0, 0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
[0, 1, -3,  0, 0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
[1, 3,  1,  0, 0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
[0, 0,  0, -1, 0,  0, -3,  0,  0],
[0, 0,  0,  0, 0, -3,  0, -3,  0],
[0, 0,  0,  1, 3,  0,  0,  0, -3],
[0, 0,  0,  3, 0,  0, -1,  0,  0],
[0, 0,  0,  0, 3,  0,  0,  0, -3],
[0, 0,  0,  0, 0,  3,  1,  3,  0]])
>>> Matrix(M).rank()
6
```

Hence, we have $3^2 - 6 = 3$ degrees of freedom.

Comment: Yes I know realised that the answer I posted only works for PAP^-1

P^-1AP allows you to set all three unknowns, as long as resulting P is invertible.

Answer (score 2):

The computation is correct, and we cannot expect that $P$ is unique in general. A somewhat extreme case is $A=B=0$, where *any* invertible $P$ will do.